# Why the need of java unicode when decimal representation is there?

Tags: java, unicode

```
package Test;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args)  {
       char b=65;
       char B='\u0041';
      //aren't these same?
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably because native character set for Java programming language is the Unicode and English is not the only language in the world.

> Programs are written using the Unicode character set.
>   © [JLS §3.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.1)

In compiled Java program `char b = 65` and `char b = '\u0041'` will produce absolutely equivalent bytecode. But the Unicode escape sequence (\uXXXX) can be used anywhere in source code, not only in string or character literal definition, while number representation not.

Short example:

```
public class HelloWorld {

    public static void \u006D\u0061\u0069\u006E(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, world!");
    }

}
```

This is absolutely correct "hello world" program with main(String[] args) method. 
Further reading: [JLS §3.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.2)

Answer (score 0):

These two are same simply run to check value `equal`

```
System.out.println(b==B);
```

output will be `true`

> The Unicode standard was initially designed using 16 bits to encode
>   characters because the primary machines were 16-bit PCs.
>
> When the specification for the Java language was created, the Unicode
>   standard was accepted and the char primitive was defined as a 16-bit
>   data type, with characters in the hexadecimal range from 0x0000 to
>   0xFFFF.

Refer [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/unicode.html)

Answer (score 0):

Java doesn't need to have a unicode reprentation, but it is more comfortable in some context to use unicode.